# Size of my list doesn't increase when i type in my SearchView?

Tags: java, android-studio, search

So in searching through through whilst I type in a search View the size does not increase. so it never gets a chance to go through a for loop.

```
private void search(String newText) {
    ArrayList<GarbageInfo> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GarbageInfo object : myList){
      if (object.getName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
        myList.add(object);
      }
    }
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(myList);
    mGarbageList.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Below this is where the searchView set onQueryListener is. I don't believe there could be something wrong in this, but I could be wrong.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          search(newText);
          return true;
        }
      });
```

Would really appreciate the help, if anything more is required I will try to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a logical error, because these two lines don't make much sense:

```
ArrayList<GarbageInfo> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (GarbageInfo object : myList){
```

You are creating a new list and then trying to immediately iterate through its elements. So you are always iterating an empty list, so the statements in the `for` block will never be executed.